# Error as connect ECONNREFUSED when using node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a link between node.js and mysql. I get an error as connect ECONNREFUSED. how to solve ths?

**CODE:**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');



var conn = mysql.createConnection({

        host : "192.164.0.114",
        user : "supriya",
        password : "root123@",
        database: "student"
}
);


var queryString = "SELECT * FROM studata";

conn.query("someurlhere",queryString, function(error, results)
{

    if(error)
    {
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        console.log(results);
    }

})

conn.end();
```

Error is:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/supriya/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/supriya/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/supriya/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/home/supriya/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:387:10)
    at Connection.query (/home/supriya/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:174:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/supriya/node_js/example2.js:19:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: This error usually means that a server is not running. Do you have a mysql server process up and running? perhaps you need to specify a port?

Maybe double check your mysql user/pass too after that.

Comment: @Sgnl `ECONNREFUSED` cannot possibly mean a wrong username or password.

Comment: @EJP yeah, you're right. It's the double-double checker in me. :O

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I invoked `node server.js`, which says

> It's Started on PORT 3000 Problem with MySQLError: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED

By first line, I assumed, intially, it starts mysql server. However, that is not the case. it starts node server, which tries to connect to mysql server and node server says ECONNREFUSED. Clearly, mysql server was not running. I found this, when I logged in, as root, in mysql workbench and tried to execute simple query. There in the corner it said, "..at port 3306, it is not connected" or sth like that.
So, conclusion is starting server.js on some port starts node server and not mysql server.